# Logic for getting last entered row inside the HTML page before submit

Tags: javascript

Hi Below is my requirement and I am trying to solve an issue.Please help

I have an HTML page intially with 5 empty rows as shown below
[image]

If the user fills out all 5 rows another 5 rows will be refreshed
For this I am calling to java server side action by adding new rows to the arraylist. Each row is uniquely identified by large number and type of column
for eg:

```
for name
<input type="text" name="N-1111110001" value="" size="8" maxlength="12" ></td>
for comments
<input type="text" name="C-1111110001" value="" size="30" maxlength="30"></td>
for organization
<select name="O-1111110001">
```

So if the user calls for submit after filling 'n' number of rows
I have to get the last filled row with values for iteration from 1111110001 to 111111000n

To know that I thought of using javascript for actullay sending the last entered values of row as part of URL to server
where I can do further saving.
The below is the function.

```
function doFormActionAfterValidating(form,actionStr)
 {    

    var valuearray = new Array();
    var nameXS='N-';
     var namearray = new Array();
      valuearray.length = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++)
       {
           if (document.forms[i].name == 'dailyTaskListForm')
           {
              for (j = 0; j < document.forms[i].elements.length; j++)
              {
                 if (document.forms[i].elements[j].name == 'tid')
                 {
                     valuearray[i]=nameXS.concat(document.forms[i].elements[j].value)
                     alert("valuearray[i]-"+valuearray[i]);


                 }
              }
           }
       }////This will give me array of values associated with names'
    ///Now my next step is find the last filled values out of these.

    for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++)
            {
               if (document.forms[i].name == 'dailyTaskListForm')
               {
                  for (j = 0; j < document.forms[i].elements.length; j++)
                  {
                     if (document.forms[i].elements[j].name == valuearray[j])
                     {
                         namearray[i]=document.forms[i].elements[j].value
                         alert("namearray[i]-"+namearray[i]);


                     }
                  }
               }
            }      



 }
```

I am stuck at getting values from the array.Please help

Comment: Can't help, but I hope being "struck" was not painful :D

Comment: What do you see in those alerts? What happens?

Comment: valuearray[i]-N-1111110005,N-1111110004,N-1111110003,N-1111110002,N-1111110001. Now I have get value of the array items .How?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this approach?:

```
<input type="text" name="field1[]" value="" size="8" maxlength="12" >
<input type="text" name="field2[]" value="" size="30" maxlength="30"> 

<input type="text" name="field1[]" value="" size="8" maxlength="12" >
<input type="text" name="field2[]" value="" size="30" maxlength="30">
```

And than get the values in PHP by looping:

```
foreach($_POST['field1'] as $i => $val){
  $field1 = $val;
  $field2 = $_POST['field2'][$i];

  // Do something with it..
}
```

Comment: actually this was designed so by someone else perhaps can do only to use existing method

Comment: Okay, well...please drill down your example to the core problem and clearify what data you have after posting and want you want to accomplish. Maybe we can be more of a help that way.